# WordPress Media URL conflicts with Page URL

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

If I upload a file `foo.pdf` to WordPress I can access it at `http://example.com/foo/`. (There is a simple HTML page with a link to the PDF file).

If I then create a Page named `foo` I cannot view or preview the Page because the default URL, `http://example.com/foo/`, will resolve to the page for the PDF.

How can I resolve this URL conflict?

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, WordPress's URL redirection uses the `-f` flag, so it applies the "nice URL" rule only if the requested file doesn't exist. I think you could say that is the proper behaviour.

The easiest way would be storing the PDF elsewhere, for example in the `/wp-content` directory that is exempt from URL rewriting. Is that not an option?

Comment: The PDF is in `wp-content/uploads` but WordPress creates a page at `http://example.com/foo/` which has a link to the PDF.

Comment: @Liam so this is an internal WordPress conflict? Or are you using a plug-in for the uploads?

Comment: Yes, it is a very basic installation, no plugins. v2.9.2

Comment: I just encountered the exact same problem. My media item is a jpeg uploaded normally into `wp-content/uploads/`